# Negative z index not working on ::after pseudo element

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend, pseudo-element

I do not get why the pseudo element ::after doesn't go behind the blue box when I put the z-index as a negative value with the other divs having no z-index values. As of the moment the blue box is behind the yellow box but I want the yellow box to be below the blue box but above the red one.

```css
.menu1{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.menu1 .menupicture1{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.menu1 .menupicture1::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu1">
        <div class="menupicture1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `position:absolute` in pseudo element.

update css part below:

```
.menu1 .menupicture1::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  position:absolute; /* add this property */
}
```

```css
.menu1{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.menu1 .menupicture1{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.menu1 .menupicture1::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu1">
        <div class="menupicture1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give elements a `position`.

[more info](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

```css
.menu1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.menu1 .menupicture1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.menu1 .menupicture1::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu1">
  <div class="menupicture1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use negative `z-index` on the **red** box and **yellow** box, and add `position:relative;` to them

```css
.menu1{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position:relative;
  z-index: -1;
  
}
.menu1 .menupicture1{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  background-color: blue;

}

.menu1 .menupicture1::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position:relative;
  z-index: -1;

}
```

```html
<div class="menu1">
        <div class="menupicture1"></div>
</div>
```